# Repository Authentication with Basic Auth only works when embedded in URL

Tags: maven

I have a private maven repository. Publishing on this repository with authentication works well. But when I try use the repository to resolve dependencies, the authentication credentials defined in the `settings.xml` are not applied. Only way to make it work is to provide the credentials in the repository URL defined in the `pom.xml`

Is this a bug or did I miss something during setup?

Snippet from the `pom.xml`

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>myServer</id>
        <name>My Servers Name</name>
        <url>https://someHost/repository/maven-public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Snippet from the `settings.xml`

```xml
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>myServer</id>
        <username>myUser</username>
        <password>myPass</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

I use `Apache Maven 3.0.5 (Red Hat 3.0.5-17)` and on the server's side I see that no credentials are applied, so a 401 is responded.

The above setup does work if I remove the server-setup from `settings.xml` and add the credentials `myUser:myPass` to the URL defined in the `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it appeared that I had a typo in the auth-credentials so, all works as expected.